# Regex to not match ._filename.php files

Tags: php, regex

MAC OSX creates some unwanted dot underscore files to store file information.

There are currently two files in a directory on my file system - `Test.php` and `._Test.php`.

I need to write a preg_match to accept only first file and ignore the metadata file. For eg.

```
preg_match('/^(.+)\.php$/', $fileName, $matches);
```

But, here `$matches` returns the same output for both $fileName = `Test.php` and `._Test.php`.

Is there anyway to modify the regex to ignore the metadata file and accept only `Test.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that the string doesn't start with `._`:

```
^(?!\._)(.+)\.php$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gBqaM7/2)

PHP sample

```
<?php
$tests[] = "Test.php";
$tests[] = "._Test.php";
$tests[] = ".Testing.php";
$tests[] = "_Testing2.php";
$tests[] = "._greajo.com";
$tests[] = "_.greajo.com";
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    if (preg_match("/^(?!\._)(.+)\.php$/i", $test, $m)) {
        echo "Valid file: ".$m[1].PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        echo "Invalid file".PHP_EOL; // discard?
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4dKKj)

*Result*

> Valid file: Test
>
> Invalid file
>
> Valid file: .Testing
>
> Valid file: _Testing2
>
> Invalid file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to match only `.php` files and also need the filename without extension to be present in $matches[1] which was happening with my regex in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[^\.].*\.php$/', $fileName, $matches);
```

See demo https://implode.io/evnXDC